# How to divide array into small size chunks?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am fetching this array in JavaScript program by ajax in every second, the response from the request takes about 3 to 4 second to be completed. Therefore I want to this array to be split in chunks but failed to complete the array was

```
{"m":true,
"s":true,
"q":{
"eur":{"b":"1.06783","a":"1.06790","h":"1.06978","l":"1.06729"},
"gbp":{"b":"1.24407","a":"1.24416","h":"1.25093","l":"1.24397"},
"aud":{"b":"0.76456","a":"0.76464","h":"0.76630","l":"0.76387"},
"cad":{"b":"1.33550","a":"1.33557","h":"1.33583","l":"1.33251"},
"jpy":{"b":"111.996","a":"112.002","h":"112.204","l":"111.700"},
"chf":{"b":"1.00110","a":"1.00117","h":"1.00188","l":"0.99850"},
"xau":{"b":"1241.75","a":"1242.1","h":"1244.69","l":"1239.53"},
"xag":{"b":"18.056","a":"18.098","h":"18.175","l":"18.02"},
"nok":{"b":"8.58853","a":"8.5901","h":"8.59342","l":"8.55128"},
"sek":{"b":"8.9308","a":"8.9323","h":"8.9515","l":"8.92151"},
"sgd":{"b":"1.3975","a":"1.3977","h":"1.3959","l":"1.3987"},
"pkr":{"b":"104.8300","a":"105.8300","h":"104.8300","l":"104.620"},
"dkk":{"b":"6.9645","a":"6.9648","h":"6.9500","l":"6.9691"},
"nzd":{"b":"0.69835","a":"0.69859","h":"0.70084","l":"0.69794"},
"zar":{"b":"13.3688","a":"13.37396","h":"13.6475","l":"13.232"},
"hkd":{"b":"7.77017","a":"7.77098","h":"7.77244","l":"7.76847"},
"inr":{"b":"64.8500","a":"64.8600","h":"64.925","l":"64.7800"},
"try":{"b":"3.63447","a":"3.63558","h":"3.65941","l":"3.63076"},
"pln":{"b":"3.9514","a":"3.9520","h":"3.9361","l":"3.9520"},
"cnh":{"b":"6.88261","a":"6.88352","h":"6.89029","l":"6.8706"},
"myr":{"b":"0.2255","a":"0.2265","h":"0.2253","l":"0.2257"},
"sar":{"b":"0.2662","a":"0.2672","h":"0.2662","l":"0.2662"}
}}
```

Please help me, I am getting stuck on this...

Comment: that's not an array ... so, you're fighting an uphill battle

Comment: SO is not a code writing service - have you made any attempt at all?

Comment: I think it is json object.. you have to convert it first into array then chunk

Comment: @JaromandaX You are in your element mate. :-p

Comment: also ... if that 1405 bytes takes 3 to 4 seconds, you've got real issues somewhere

Comment: you should post your code where you tried and what part of your code has a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse in first:

```
var json = '{"m":true,"s":true,"q":{"eur":{"b":"1.06783","a":"1.06790","h":"1.06978","l":"1.06729"},"gbp":{"b":"1.24407","a":"1.24416","h":"1.25093","l":"1.24397"},"aud":{"b":"0.76456","a":"0.76464","h":"0.76630","l":"0.76387"},"cad":{"b":"1.33550","a":"1.33557","h":"1.33583","l":"1.33251"},"jpy":{"b":"111.996","a":"112.002","h":"112.204","l":"111.700"},"chf":{"b":"1.00110","a":"1.00117","h":"1.00188","l":"0.99850"},"xau":{"b":"1241.75","a":"1242.1","h":"1244.69","l":"1239.53"},"xag":{"b":"18.056","a":"18.098","h":"18.175","l":"18.02"},"nok":{"b":"8.58853","a":"8.5901","h":"8.59342","l":"8.55128"},"sek":{"b":"8.9308","a":"8.9323","h":"8.9515","l":"8.92151"},"sgd":{"b":"1.3975","a":"1.3977","h":"1.3959","l":"1.3987"},"pkr":{"b":"104.8300","a":"105.8300","h":"104.8300","l":"104.620"},"dkk":{"b":"6.9645","a":"6.9648","h":"6.9500","l":"6.9691"},"nzd":{"b":"0.69835","a":"0.69859","h":"0.70084","l":"0.69794"},"zar":{"b":"13.3688","a":"13.37396","h":"13.6475","l":"13.232"},"hkd":{"b":"7.77017","a":"7.77098","h":"7.77244","l":"7.76847"},"inr":{"b":"64.8500","a":"64.8600","h":"64.925","l":"64.7800"},"try":{"b":"3.63447","a":"3.63558","h":"3.65941","l":"3.63076"},"pln":{"b":"3.9514","a":"3.9520","h":"3.9361","l":"3.9520"},"cnh":{"b":"6.88261","a":"6.88352","h":"6.89029","l":"6.8706"},"myr":{"b":"0.2255","a":"0.2265","h":"0.2253","l":"0.2257"},"sar":{"b":"0.2662","a":"0.2672","h":"0.2662","l":"0.2662"}}}';
json = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(json.q.try);
```

Now you have easy access to desirable fields...

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: having access to particular fields it makes it easy to split json object:

Comment: SURE, this is json object please guide me how to convert it in array ?

Comment: @Raphael : In my opinion, The question is about how to split? So this answer is not addressing the question.

Comment: i want to reduce its size from 1.9KB to in bytes for better performance and faster execution. therefore i want to reduce its size in chunks... so how ?

Answer (score 0):

To split this into array chunks you can use $.map

```
var json = '{"m":true,"s":true,"q":{"eur":{"b":"1.06783","a":"1.06790","h":"1.06978","l":"1.06729"},"gbp":{"b":"1.24407","a":"1.24416","h":"1.25093","l":"1.24397"},"aud":{"b":"0.76456","a":"0.76464","h":"0.76630","l":"0.76387"},"cad":{"b":"1.33550","a":"1.33557","h":"1.33583","l":"1.33251"},"jpy":{"b":"111.996","a":"112.002","h":"112.204","l":"111.700"},"chf":{"b":"1.00110","a":"1.00117","h":"1.00188","l":"0.99850"},"xau":{"b":"1241.75","a":"1242.1","h":"1244.69","l":"1239.53"},"xag":{"b":"18.056","a":"18.098","h":"18.175","l":"18.02"},"nok":{"b":"8.58853","a":"8.5901","h":"8.59342","l":"8.55128"},"sek":{"b":"8.9308","a":"8.9323","h":"8.9515","l":"8.92151"},"sgd":{"b":"1.3975","a":"1.3977","h":"1.3959","l":"1.3987"},"pkr":{"b":"104.8300","a":"105.8300","h":"104.8300","l":"104.620"},"dkk":{"b":"6.9645","a":"6.9648","h":"6.9500","l":"6.9691"},"nzd":{"b":"0.69835","a":"0.69859","h":"0.70084","l":"0.69794"},"zar":{"b":"13.3688","a":"13.37396","h":"13.6475","l":"13.232"},"hkd":{"b":"7.77017","a":"7.77098","h":"7.77244","l":"7.76847"},"inr":{"b":"64.8500","a":"64.8600","h":"64.925","l":"64.7800"},"try":{"b":"3.63447","a":"3.63558","h":"3.65941","l":"3.63076"},"pln":{"b":"3.9514","a":"3.9520","h":"3.9361","l":"3.9520"},"cnh":{"b":"6.88261","a":"6.88352","h":"6.89029","l":"6.8706"},"myr":{"b":"0.2255","a":"0.2265","h":"0.2253","l":"0.2257"},"sar":{"b":"0.2662","a":"0.2672","h":"0.2662","l":"0.2662"}}}';
json = JSON.parse(json);

var arr = $.map(json.q, function(el) { return el });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert JSON data to multidimensional array.
When TRUE is passed as a second argument, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
print_r(json_decode(json_array, true));
```

After that use the [array_chunk()](http://php.net/array_chunk) function to split the multidimensional array into smaller chunks.

Example:

```
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
```

Comment: i am encoding the json object like "echo json_encode($results);"

Comment: print_r(json_decode(json_array, true));  --  doesn't print anything

Comment: you need to replace "json_array" with  $results in the function to perform.